# Euclidean Distance

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

[Hacker Rank - Weather Observation Station 19](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-19)

> Given a table STATION that holds data for five fields namely ID, CITY,
>   STATE, NORTHERN LATITUDE and WESTERN LONGITUDE.
>
> ```
> +-------------+------------+
> | Field       |   Type     |
> +-------------+------------+
> | ID          | INTEGER    |
> | CITY        | VARCHAR(21)|
> | STATE       | VARCHAR(2) |
> | LAT_N       | NUMERIC    |
> | LONG_W      | NUMERIC    |
> +-------------+------------+
> ```
>
> Consider P1(a, b) and P2(c, d) be two points on 2D plane, where (a,
>   b) be minimum and maximum values of Northern Latitude and (c, d) be
>   minimum and maximum values of Western Longitude. Write a query to
>   print the Euclidean Distance between points P1 and P2 up to 4 decimal
>   digits.

my solution for oracle is :

```
select round((abs(max(lat_n)-max(long_w)) + abs(min(long_w)-min(lat_n))),4) from station;
```

but it is giving answer to the 3 decimal points but i need 4 decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `ltrim(to_char(x, '999.9999'))`

[Number Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570)

Answer (score 2):

For MySql it works fine:

```
    SELECT ROUND(SQRT(POW(MIN(LAT_N)-MAX(LAT_N),2)+POW(MIN(LONG_W)-MAX(LONG_W),2)),4) FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 2):

**[In Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)**

**Distance**

dist((x, y), (a, b)) = sqrt ((x - a)² + (y - b)²)

This query do this operation

```
select round(sqrt (power(max(lat_n)-min(lat_n),2)+power(max(long_w)-min(long_w),2)),4)
from station
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Select round(sqrt(power((min(lat_n)-max(lat_n)),2) + power((min(long_w)-max(long_w)),2)),4) From station
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, try like this:

```
SELECT 
cast(
    round(
        SQRT(
             SQUARE((Abs ((MIN(LAT_N ) - MAX(LAT_N )))) )
           + SQUARE( (Abs((MIN(LONG_W  ) - MAX(LONG_W  )))))
            )
        ,4)
as decimal(18,4)
)
    
FROM  STATION
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL soln:

select
round( power( power((min(lat_n)-max(lat_n)),2) + power((min(long_w)-max(long_w)),2),1/2),4) as distance
from station;

in this code I have used power(x,1/2) instead of sqrt(x) ..so that when needed to find nth root in future we can use power(x, 1/y) operation ( where y = 0,1,2,..,n).

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer...   in MySQL

```
select round(SQRT(pow(min(LAT_N) - max(LAT_N),2) + pow(min(LONG_W) - max(LONG_W),2)),4)
from station
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
select
    cast(sqrt((power(max(lat_n)-min(lat_n),2))+(power(max(long_w)-in(long_w),2))) as decimal(16,4))
from station;
```

Comment: Could you add more verbal explanations to your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(sqrt(((MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N))*(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N))) 
+ ((MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W))*(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)))),4)
```

from station;

Try this in ORACLE SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    CAST( SQRT( POWER(MIN(LAT_N)
        - MAX(LAT_N), 2)
            + POWER(MIN(LONG_W)
                - MAX( LONG_W), 2)) AS DECIMAL (10, 4))
FROM STATION
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT ROUND(SQRT(POWER(((MAX(LONG_W))-(MIN(LONG_W))),2)+POWER(((MAX(LAT_N))-(MIN(LAT_N))),2)),4)
FROM STATION
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

correct your SQL Query -- (min(lat_n) - max(lat_n))+abs(min(long_w) - max(long_w)) --

**Euclidean distance**

**Definition: The straight line distance between two points. In a plane with p1 at (x1, y1) and p2 at (x2, y2), it is √((x1 - x2)² + (y1 - y2)²).**

```
select round(sqrt(power((min(lat_n) - max(lat_n)),2) + power((min(long_w) - max(long_w)),2)),4) from station
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code using Oracle.

```
SELECT 
ROUND(SQRT(POWER(ABS(MIN(LAT_N) - MAX(LAT_N)),2) + POWER(ABS(MIN(LONG_W) - MAX(LONG_W)),2)) , 4)
FROM STATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(ltrim(sqrt(power(max(LAT_N) - min(LAT_N), 2) + power(max(LONG_W) - min(LONG_W), 2)),'999.9999'), 4) FROM STATION;
```

This is the code that worked for me on the DB2 editor on hackerank

```
select round(sqrt(power(max(LAT_N) - min(LAT_N), 2) + power(max(LONG_W) - min(LONG_W), 2)), 4) FROM STATION;
```

This is the code that worked for me on the MySQL editor on hackerank

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in MySQL:**
select ROUND(ABS(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N)) + ABS(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)), 4) FROM STATION;

Answer (score -1):

It will work for sure.

```
DECLARE @a numeric(36,4),@b numeric(36,4),@c numeric(36,4),@d numeric(36,4)
SET @a=(SELECT MIN(CAST(ROUND(LAT_N,4) as numeric(36,4))) FROM STATION);
SET @b=(SELECT MIN(CAST(ROUND(LONG_W ,4) as numeric(36,4))) FROM STATION);
SET @c=(SELECT MAX(CAST(ROUND(LAT_N,4) as numeric(36,4))) FROM STATION);
SET @d=(SELECT MAX(CAST(ROUND(LONG_W ,4) as numeric(36,4))) FROM STATION);
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(ROUND((POWER(((POWER((@c-@a),2))+(POWER((@d-@b),2))),0.5)),4) as numeric(36,4)) FROM STATION
```

Comment: Euclidean Distance = SquareRoot(((x2-x1)^2)+((y2-y1)^2))
SquareRoot can be written as (something)^(0.5)
I implemented like that.
CAST(ROUND(LONG_W ,4) as numeric(36,4)) is for taking value upto 4 decimal point.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select round(sqrt(POWER((MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N)),2) 
    + POWER((MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W)),2)),4)
from station;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  LTRIM(
          TO_CHAR(
            SQRT(
              POWER(MAX(LAT_N) - MIN(LAT_N), 2) +
              POWER(MAX(LONG_W) - MIN(LONG_W), 2)
            ),
            '999.9999'
          )
        ) 
FROM    STATION;
```

Comment: Try to edit answer with some explanation to it, so OP and other can understand it better.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ROUND(POWER(POWER(MAX(Station.LAT_N) -MIN(Station.LAT_N),2) + POWER(MAX(Station.LONG_W) - MIN(Station.Long_W),2),0.5), 4) 
FROM Station;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to it, so other can understand it better

Comment: a= min value of LAT_N,
b= max value of LAT_N,
c= min value of LONG_W,
d= max value of LONG_W,
in this case the formula will be like: 
Euclidean distance= sqrt(sq(a-b) +sq(c-d))