# Oracle SQL to perform local outlier factors (LOF) with euclidean-distance

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have sample data as below and I wanted to perform **local outlier factors (LOF) with euclidean-distance** and then filter/identify out of normal values. I know we can easily do this using ML Platform, but curious if we can achieve the same using oracle SQL.

```
DT     DEPT_ID  SAL
201907   10      5      
201907   10      28378  
201907   10      34     
201907   10      2      
201907   10      1800   
201907   10      723        
201907   10      701            
201907   10      38877  
201907   10      3628   
201907   10      16818.28   
201907   10      10         
201907   10      3574.16        
201907   10      199994.73  
201907   10      1073173        
201907   10      1999999.94 
201907   10      468682.16  
201907   10      19999997.15    
201907   10      21999998.46    
201907   10      16580003.29    
201907   10      5909999.69 
201907   10      49130  
201907   10      10000
```

expected result. Here outlier >50 is out of normal

```
 LOF_outlier    date     dept_id   sal
        0.8      201907   10        2
        0.8      201907   10        5
        0.8      201907   10        10
        0.8      201907   10        34
        0.8      201907   10        701
        0.8      201907   10        723
        0.9      201907   10        1800
        1.0      201907   10        3574
        1.0      201907   10        3628
        2.2      201907   10        10000
        2.9      201907   10        16818
        3.9      201907   10        28378
        4.9      201907   10        38877
        6.4      201907   10        49130
        26.3     201907   10        199994
        50.7     201907   10        468682
        73.4     201907   10        1073173
        125.0    201907   10        1999999
        274.6    201907   10        5909999
        311.3    201907   10        16580003
        373.5    201907   10        19999997
        411.3    201907   10        21999998
```

Comment: SQL is not designed for statistical analysis.  Some statistical functions are included, and many databases have interfaces to R or Python or some other language.  However, phrased as a statistical question, a database isn't appropriate.  If you can phrase it as a simpler data processing problem ("what values are in the top 5%?"), then a database is more appropriate tool.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - while what you said is true, it is also true that whenever the "processing" can be done "close to the database", that will have definite advantages. In this case, a well-designed PL/SQL package may provide significant efficiencies when the amount of data to analyze is massive. I will just add the `plsql` tag since I think it's relevant here.

Comment: Even thought I taught graduate-level statistic courses in my previous career in academia, I confess I had not heard of the LOF method. (Not surprisingly since I left academia in 2000, when this method was published.) I did some reading, and from what I'm seeing it's quite elementary and can be implemented easily both in plain SQL and in PL/SQL. The PL/SQL route is likely better (even if it simply wraps a pure SQL solution within a function call) - "write once, use everywhere" philosophy. But, I have a couple of questions for you.

Comment: First, why "Euclidean distance"? That makes sense in multi-dimensional data; your data is unidimensional. Of course, taking the absolute value of differences is in fact the one-dimensional Euclidean distance, but using that phrase for it sounds pompous. Second, and more seriously, the LOF method produces a "score" depending on a positive integer parameter $k$. You didn't mention it. What did you use when you generated your desired output?

Comment: @mathguy Thank you. I used lower bound 10 and upper bound 20 for Euclidian distance. I see someone calculated Euclidian distance here, but i cant get this working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892453/euclidean-distance?rq=1.. any help??

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "lower bound 10 and upper bound 20 for Euclidean distance"? Is your data, in fact, uni-dimensional, or are you also considering factors other than `SAL`? The thread you linked to has two-dimensional data. And, what value for `k` did you use? (Or is **that** what you were referring to with lower and upper bounds? - and if so, did you compute the LOF for the range, and then the average over that range of `k`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt to compute the LOF (local outlier factors) for the data in your sample. As I stated in a Comment to your question, there isn't just one set of LOF; there is a parameterized family, depending on a positive integer parameter `k`, which I modeled as a bind variable below.

I computed the LOF for different values of `k`; I wasn't able to match your output (and, indeed, I wonder if your output is in fact correct). In any case, this is a demonstration of the concept - if my math or my code (or both) is incorrect, that can be fixed.

Here is a link to the original (2000) paper in which the LOF concept was introduced; the relevant definitions are on pages 3 and 4. https://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/LOF.pdf

The subqueries in the `WITH` clause below follow the definitions step by step - k-**d**istance in subquery `d`, k-distance **n**eighborhood and reachability distance in subquery `n`, **l**ocal reachability density in `l`, and the local outlier factors in the final query. Below I show the query, and the results for `k = 12`.

```
variable k number
exec :k := 12

with
  p (rn, sal) as (
    select row_number() over (order by sal), sal 
    from   t
  )
, b (rn, sal, dist, drk) as (
    select p.rn, p.sal, abs(p1.sal - p.sal), 
           row_number() over (partition by p.sal order by abs(p1.sal - p.sal)) 
    from   p join p p1 on p1.rn between p.rn - :k and p.rn + :k
  )
, d (rn, sal, kdist) as (
    select b.rn, b.sal, b.dist
    from   b
    where  b.drk = :k + 1
  )
, n (rn, sal, pt_rn, pt, rdist) as (
    select d.rn, d.sal, d1.rn, d1.sal, greatest(abs(d1.sal - d.sal), d1.kdist)
    from   d join d d1 on abs(d1.sal - d.sal) <= d.kdist and d1.rn != d.rn
  )
, l (rn, sal, lrd) as (
    select rn, sal, 1/avg(rdist)
    from   n
    group  by rn, sal
  )
select l.sal as sal, round(avg(l1.lrd) / l.lrd, 2) as lof
from   n join l    on n.rn    = l.rn
         join l l1 on n.pt_rn = l1.rn
group  by l.rn, l.sal, l.lrd
order  by l.rn
;
```

Output:

```
       SAL        LOF
---------- ----------
         2        .99
         5        .99
        10        .99
        34        .99
       701        .99
       723        .99
      1800        .99
   3574.16          1
      3628          1
     10000       1.01
  16818.28       1.03
     28378       1.02
     38877          1
     49130       1.23
 199994.73       5.21
 468682.16      11.36
   1073173      23.08
1999999.94      39.61
5909999.69     106.26
16580003.3     196.89
19999997.2     227.52
21999998.5     245.42
```